# can an attacker exploit my main site from subdomain?

Tags: sub-domain

I have an app that was in a folder on my main site's root directory `www.example.com/app` which was recently hacked and the entire website was offline because the server load was too high and the database was corrupted somehow.

Now, before I find the exploit in the app I would like to have it back online. Would placing it in a subdomain like `app.example.com` make any difference? Assuming the attacker will do the same on the new location, is my main site safer?

Comment: What do you mean by "hacked"?

Comment: Don't know another term for it. Some IP is hitting the app registration form page with a GET, followed with a POST and then it gets redirected to the main site. I'm not a security expert but I'm pretty sure this is the cause for the server load I've mentioned and problems I've had. Removed the app and all is working fine for 2 days now.

Comment: I've checked the IP and it's responsible for 5000 attacks in the last days. If anyone is interested this is the IP 188.138.188.34.

Comment: I guess this answers my question. "In addition to cookie theft, the ability to load arbitrary code on a subdomain could also help attackers to bypass same-origin and cross-domain security restrictions for the corresponding domain.". Taken from - https://www.pcworld.com/article/2857212/forgotten-subdomains-boost-risk-of-account-hijacking-other-attacks.html

Comment: Were you actually hacked or do you just have high load due to automated bots effectively causing a DoS?  Because it sounds like the latter, in which case "hacked" is not applicable and the solutions are *completely* different.  I think you need to clarify what your problem is.

Comment: For the record, "5000 attacks in the last days" is not a lot.  Any publicly accessible website will get fake form submissions from bots from almost the instant it comes online.  Even 5000 fake requests a day is less than 4 a minute, which is a tiny amount of traffic.  If 5000 requests spread out over days is taking down your server, then your application is in real trouble.

Comment: from the looks of it, the memory and cpu load was from within the server and not from external bots causing a DoS attack. I'm assuming that the attacker managed to run a script in the server from the registration form and this has caused this. Could not tell for sure from the logs I can access and the host provider was of no help at all. After I deleted the application, the website is working as it should for now, and I'll keep a close eye on it.

Comment: by 5000 attacks I was referring to 5000 reports made by other people. This is what I was referring to - https://cleantalk.org/blacklists/188.138.188.34

Comment: I think you need to figure out whether or not you are hacked and what is going on with your server.  From what I can tell you have a high server load (which could be malware, but could be lots of other things), you have an IP address that is spamming your page (which is usually completely unrelated to malware), and you want to try to change domain names to fix everything.  How can anyone know if your proposed change will help when you aren't even sure what is actually going on?

Comment: I only wanted to know if a subdomain attack can alter the main domain, which I found it can, so I got the app on another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, before I find the exploit in the app I would like to have it back
>   online

Now since you don't know what kind of "hack" it is.I am gonna go ahead and assume that it's a remote code execution,which means now the attacker can execute arbitrary code in the server.If that is the case then your server is compromised.The only way now is to start clean and plug the bug.

> Now, before I find the exploit in the app I would like to have it back
>   online. Would placing it in a subdomain like app.example.com make any
>   difference

Yes,**If and only if** the (application with the bug) points to a different machine then and only then is the attack separated from the main application which is now in a different machine

> Some IP is hitting the app registration form page with a GET, followed
>   with a POST and then it gets redirected to the main site. I'm not a
>   security expert but I'm pretty sure this is the cause for the server
>   load I've mentioned and problems I've had

Now that you mention this.This seems more like a DOS or Searching a vuln of some kind.There are better solutions to prevent that like DOS Protection or even a Web application firewall along with it.

> I've checked the IP and it's responsible for 5000 attacks in the last
>   days. If anyone is interested this is the IP 188.138.188.34.

Simply blacklist the I.P address and do the above things i mentioned.

Comment: my question was in regards to the same server's subdomain, like here.samedomain.com and I assume it's working on the same machine which won't work. Will get another domain + host and place it there. I'll redirect the traffic to this new server and hopefully my main site will be OK. Thanks for your anwer

Comment: Or you could try blacklisting along with a web application firewall or a dos protection service.Moving your application to another machine should not be your solution

Comment: I have already blocked that IP and it's no longer causing any trouble but an IP can easily be changed. I'm moving to another server until I find what exploit was found in the app, while also keeping it online without affecting my main site.